# Do political leaders get to see early screenings of movies?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

I notice that in the recent movie [Captain America: Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America:_Civil_War), the Tony Stark character uses the expression "off the reservation". Hillary Clinton, in an interview, used the same expression. However, Clinton's interview took place a week or before the release of the movie. Is this just a freak coincidence, or did Clinton see an early screening of the movie? Do VIPs and powerful politicians get to see early private screenings of upcoming movies?

Comment: Is this even an extremely rare or unique expression to begin with?

Comment: This is a very common phrase. Unless they said it in the exact same context, I don't see how these 2 things are connected.

Comment: this is the most random thought-process-to-question i've ever seen.

Comment: 1. The phrase "Off the reservation" is so common it is cliched.  2.  This is called the ["Baader Meinhof phenomenon"](https://psmag.com/there-s-a-name-for-that-the-baader-meinhof-phenomenon-e5bf3ea87cd2#.z5shjk5jo) or ["frequency illusion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases#Frequency_illusion).

Comment: P.S. High ranking government officials, and definitely people who are *currently running for president*, barely have the time to see any film at all, let alone 150-minute blockbusters. They barely have time to *breathe*.

Comment: As strange as the thought process is to develop this question, it is a solid question. I'll upvote.

Comment: Considering that Obama [reportedly requested early access to episodes of GoT](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2014/jul/24/the-wire-obama-seinfeld-scalia-tv-leader), I think we're slightly overestimating their lack of free time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just knowing certain people can get you into all kinds of screenings. When I lived in Los Angeles I was friends with an *aspiring* screenwriter who worked as a production assistant (pretty much the lowest possible job title) at a major studio. He was able to get into several different kinds of screenings and invited me onto "the lot" a few times to attend such events. Advance screenings are not always great events. Often there are no celebrities, you might not even see the final cut of the movie, which means it might not be a very good version of the film, and they are often shown in a small, drab screening room in some random building in the corner of the production company lot.

With that in mind, anyone in a position to know any Hollywood celebrity is probably getting invites to all kinds of things, including advance screenings and premiers. That means that many politicians, epecially those who rub elbows with more politically-minded celbrities, are probably being invited to screenings. Politicians who have movies made in their districts or by their constituents are probably invited to different movie-related events.

The ironic thing is, once you're above a certain level of importance, you are too busy to attend such events, or at least you want to *appear* too busy, so the top executives in Hollywood and other VIPs pretty much never go to all the little events that they could attend if they wanted to. So politicians who are invited to entertainment industry events probably attend very few of them, if any, either because they are busy or they at least want to appear to be busy and/or working hard. At the same time, for an event that might help a politician's image, they are much more likely to attend if invited and even try to get an invite.